# Custom UITableView cell Nib file only shows up after select cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinib

When I load my app [this is what happens.](http://gfycat.com/InconsequentialSameBlackwidowspider) For some reason the table view loads blank. And only when I select the cell and click another cell does the previously selected cell show up. But for the first cell, no matter where/how I click I still can't see the first cell.

I don't understand why this happening b/c I followed [this tutorial.](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) Obviously I'm doing something wrong and would be very grateful if someone could tell me why this is happening & how to fix it.

In the main storyboard I'm using a `tableViewController SummaryTableViewController` and a custom `UITableViewCell DayOfWeekTableViewCell`. I have a nib file for the table view cell called `DayofWeekSpendingTableViewCell.xib`. [Here's a list of all my files and their fileneames.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkH8B.png)

This is my `SummaryTableViewController` code:

```
class SummaryTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var dayOfWeek: [String] = [String]()
    var totalSpentPerDay: [Double] = [Double]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dayOfWeek = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"]
        totalSpentPerDay = [0, 7.27, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dayOfWeek.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("summaryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayOfWeekTableViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let nib = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DayofWeekSpendingTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)
        cell = nib[0] as! DayOfWeekTableViewCell

        cell.dayOfWeek.text = dayOfWeek[indexPath.row]
        cell.totalAmountSpent.text = String(totalSpentPerDay[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

This is my custom cell `DayOfWeekTableViewCell` code:

```
class DayOfWeekTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dayOfWeek: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalAmountSpent: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

In the main storyboard, I've...

- [connected the custom cell `DayOfWeekTableViewCell` to the storyboard cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhRkT.png)
- [identified the storyboard cell as `summaryCell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTVYK.png)

In the nib file `DayofWeekSpendingTableViewCell.xib` I've...

- [connected my nib files to custom cell `DayOfWeekTableViewCell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCEv3.png)
- [identified my nib file as `nibCell`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CurDD.png)
- [connected the outlets in my nib file to
  custom cell `DayOfWeekTableViewCell`](http://gfycat.com/PowerfulImportantConch)

Comment: Can you post the code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: Why you are not checking cell == nil in your code ? Why you defined two cells (1 in xib and 1 in storyboard) ? Why you not registered the xib for using it in the tableview ?

Comment: put your code in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of loading the NIB in cellForRowAtIndexPath, load the NIB in viewDidLoad() and register it for use with your table view

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dayOfWeek = ["MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT", "SUN"]
    totalSpentPerDay = [0, 7.27, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0]
    // Create a nib for reusing
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "DayofWeekSpendingTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "summaryCell")
}
```

Then you could directly access the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("summaryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DayOfWeekTableViewCell
    cell.dayOfWeek.text = dayOfWeek[indexPath.row]
    cell.totalAmountSpent.text = String(totalSpentPerDay[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

Comment: you probably want to remove the first `var cell = ...`, dequeuing twice in a single call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` results in odd behaviour, not to mention that this won't compile due to the redefinition of cell :p

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I will remove this typo! Thanks

Comment: I was having issues, but as Alex Popov pointed out I needed to be careful when dequeuing cells. I had conflicting dequeues.